# One static_assert makes another static_assert fail (is_default_constructible for inner class)

Tags: c++, inner-classes, type-traits, default-constructor, static-assert

The following code compiles:

```
struct Bar
{
    struct Foo
    {
        int v = 0;
    };

    // If uncomment the following line, both static assert will fail
    // static_assert(std::is_default_constructible_v<Foo>);
};

static_assert(std::is_default_constructible_v<Bar::Foo>);
```

But if I uncomment the first `static_assert`, both `static_assert` will fail. How can this happen?

See code in http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64e9c020056e37ed

Comment: I had a weird bug that looked just like that one, where a type trait would fail for a seemingly unrelated reason.

Comment: FWIW: g++ and clang both fail, icc and msvc both succeed. https://godbolt.org/z/msdv3i

Comment: Isn't it that commented static_assert requires the class type to be complete to work properly?

Comment: @cplusogl `Foo` is complete by then.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, it seems complete, but is it? Is it compiler dependent issue or it's somehow standarized?

Comment: @cplusogl, if you change the first `static_assert` to `static constexpr bool x = std::is_default_constructible_v<Foo>;` it is valid, and `is_default_constructible_v` requires full definition. Still causes the second `static_assert` to fail though.